# Hide dynamically created div in java script with fadeIn() and fadeOut()

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

In my page, I need to show some message using a dynamically created custom div which is placed in absolute position.

**My actual need is to show the div when click on create. That div should hide and remove the element after 5 seconds if user didn't press `remove` button. And if the user press `remove` button before that 5 seconds, then the div should fadeout and remove the content on that click.**

I developed a code as below

HTML code

```
<body id="ap-bd">
    <input type="button" id="dyn-cr" value="Create" />
    <input type="button" id="dyn-rm" value="Remove" />
</body>
```

Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//................FIRST PART...........
$(document).on("click", "#dyn-cr", function(){
    html = "<div class='div-1'></div>";
    $("#ap-bd").append(html);
    $(".div-1").fadeIn("slow");
    $(".div-1").delay(5000).fadeOut(2000, function(){
        $(".div-1").remove();
    });
});

//................SECOND PART...........
$(document).on("click", "#dyn-rm", function(){
    $(".div-1").fadeOut("slow", function(){
        $(".div-1").remove();
    });
});
});
```

This code is for show the message for 5 seconds, fadeout it and remove the content. And I need to perform another thing that, when I click on the remove button, it should fadeout. But that portion didnt work. It executes the click event of remove button. But the `fadeOut()` portion in the second part dont working.

At the same time, the below code is working if i use this in second part(this is an alternate way which I use for working now but I dont want to prefer this)

```
$(document).on("click", "#dyn-rm", function(){
    $(".div-1").remove();
    });
});
```

What is wrong with the first code?

The working **[JSFIDDLE Code](http://jsfiddle.net/arunsankars1989/8WL57/)**

Please help

Comment: you are removing div1 when you click create button..so there is no div1 to remove when clicking remove

Comment: @Pranav, That is an alternate way which i use now.

Comment: use $(".div-1").hide() method

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8WL57/3/    ..is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Pranav: thank you for the replay. I already try this and it is working. But I need to hide it after 5 seconds if the user didn't click on remove button. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: @Arun see this demo [http://jsfiddle.net/8WL57/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/8WL57/9/)

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8WL57/10/)**

In your code once you created a div then you removed in same function .so don't remove instead of you have to use hide method

```
     $(document).ready(function () {

    var timeInterVal = 0;
    $(document).on("click", "#dyn-cr", function () {
        html = "<div class='div-1'></div>";
        $("#ap-bd").append(html);
        $(".div-1").fadeIn("slow");
        timeInterVal = setInterval(test, 5000);
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#dyn-rm", function () {

        clearInterval(timeInterVal);
        $(".div-1").remove();

    });

    function test() {
        $(".div-1").fadeOut(2000, function () {
            $(".div-1").remove();
            clearInterval(timeInterVal);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I already mentioned it.  The actual result which I need is to hide the div and remove the contents after 5 seconds if the user didn't click on remove button. And if he press on remove button, then hide and and remove the div. Is there any way for do that?

Comment: Please check your demo. It is not working. It works as before.

Comment: @Arun i removed some thing so pls check demo ..tel me any changes if you want

Answer (score 0):

1.when you click on create button.you implement function to fadout.so,it hides.

2.)if you want to hide on remove ,you have to show on create button.

3.don't use both remove and fadeout .

only try this.

```
 $(document).on("click", "#dyn-rm", function(){

        $(".div-1").fadeOut("slow", function(){

        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8WL57/2/

Comment: Thank u for the help. This I already tried. But the actual result which I need is to hide the div and remove the contents after 5 seconds if the user didn't click on any key. And if he press on remove button, then hide and and remove the div. Is there any way for do that?

Comment: hide and remove will work same thing....chck now....is this you want ?http://jsfiddle.net/8WL57/7/

Comment: This is what I am doing now. Is `hide()` and `remove()` works as same? I don't think so. the element will remain there after `hide()`. But it will be removed from the page after `remove()`

Comment: If you just want to hide/show an object from time to time, then use jQuery .hide() and .show().

remove() (while saving and then reinserting the same object back in the DOM later) will be of little use to you because it destroys some of the data associated with the object so you may not be be able to easily reinsert it in the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this using setInterval.

```
var interVal = 0;
    $(document).on("click", "#dyn-cr", function(){
        html = "<div class='div-1'></div>";
        $("#ap-bd").append(html);
        $(".div-1").fadeIn("slow");
         interVal = setInterval(hide, 5000);

    });
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8WL57/12/